# How to edit my storyboard graphically?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xib

Somehow I got Xcode to display the storyboard file as text. Now I want to get back to the normal graphical editing mode but I can't find how to do that. What controls whether it is editing graphically or textually?

Answer (score 0):

A minute after I posted this question I discovered the answer. While editing the storyboard in text mode, click on the icon at the upper left corner of the window that looks like four tiny squares arranged in a somewhat larger square. A context menu drops down. One of the items on that menu converts the edit mode (and the display mode) to graphical. I don't know what menu item because I clicked it and now it's gone. I now see there is no item on the drop-down menu that will go back to text mode. I don't currently need text mode but I'd like to know how to readily select either mode.

Comment: To switch to text editor, find your XIB file in Project navigator, open its context menu and select "Open as → Source Code".